# Wordpress update_user

Tags: hook, php, wordpress

Нужно после регистрации юзера записывать в user_nicename его ID.
Прочекать заранее не получается т.к. ID неизвестен.
Такой хук почему то не срабатывает.

```
function get_new_nicename($user_id){
wp_update_user( array ('user_nicename'
=> $user_id) ) ; } add_action('user_register','get_new_nicename',10);
```

На форуме WP как на англоязычном, так и на русском никто ничего как всегда не знает.

В эту таблицу вообще не пишет, даже так. В чем косяк?

```
add_action('user_register','write_new_nicename',10);
function write_new_nicename($user_id){
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update(
$wpdb->prefix . 'users',
array('user_url' => $user_id),
array(
'ID' => $user_id,
'user_login' => 'display_name'
),
array( '%s' ),
array(
'%d',
'%s'
)
);}
```

**Решение:**

```
add_action('user_register','write_new_nicename',10);
 function write_new_nicename($user_id){
 global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->update(
 $wpdb->prefix . 'users',
 array('user_nicename' => $user_id),
 array('ID' => $user_id)
 );
 }
```

Comment: Что выдает  

    var_dump( $user_id )
внутри хука ?

Comment: Приходит int(86) сразу после реги

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том что Вы вешаете хук уже после того как отработала функция wp_insert_user(); а нужно это сделать до. Если Вы поместите Вашу конструкцию

```
`function get_new_nicename($user_id){
wp_update_user( array ('user_nicename'
=> $user_id) ) ; } add_action('user_register','get_new_nicename',10);
`
```

в главный файл плагина то все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

проще вручную sql запрос написать.

Comment: Не хочется говнокодить, если есть стандартные функции

Comment: весь вордпресс один сплошной говнокод. если вам еще много подобных вещей делать - забейте. много времени потратите.

Comment: все что нужно я уже пофиксил. провозился около двух месяцев. 
а это уже так..не принципиально.